# Does getenv cache the result?

Tags: c++, optimization, environment-variables

I have several calls to `getenv` in my code(called a lot of times), so I see the potential for an optimization. My question is, does `getenv` somehow cache the result internally, or does it query the environment variables on each call?

I have profiled the code, `getenv` is not a bottleneck, but I'd still like to change it if it's more efficient.

As a side question, can an environment variable be changed for a program while it is running? I'm not doing that, so in my case caching the result would be safe, it's just curiosity.

Comment: How can you be sure that no user will change the env variables at runtime?

Answer (score 4):

Environment variables usually live in the memory of given process so there is nothing to cache there, they are readily available.

As for updates, any component of a running process can call `putenv` to updated the environment, you should not cache it for prolonged periods if you expect that to happen.

Comment: What do you mean by _anybody_? An external process?

Comment: @hmjd: I mean components of a running process. External applications cannot change environment of a running process on any OS I know.

Comment: that is my understanding as well. You may want to modify your answer to make that clear.

Comment: Windows (XP and later, I think) do manage to change the environment.  Launch a cmd shell, `set`.  Go to My Computer->Properties->Advanced and change the path.  Go back to the cmd shell and run `set` again.

Comment: @JimR: set output does not change, nor does %MYVAR%, only a newly started cmd shell has the new values

Comment: On unix an external application (e.g. a debugger) could attach to the process using `ptrace()` and call `putenv()` to modify the process' environment. Technically that's the same process modifying its own env, but under the control of an external process. But generally it's true only the process itself can change its environment.

Comment: @smerlin: Odd.  System Variables changed for me at one point.  I stand corrected.

Comment: @JimR: Yes, there are programs which always use the current system environment variables (not cmd.exe, but e.g. explorer.exe), but those use other means than `getenv` to get the system environment variables .

Answer (score 1):

I doubt it caches the results, environment variables could change from call to call. You can implement that cache yourself:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <cstdlib>


class EnvCache {
public:
    const std::string &get_env(const std::string &key) {
        auto it = cache_entries.find(key);
        if(it == cache_entries.end()) {
            const char *ptr = getenv(key.c_str());
            if(!ptr)
                throw std::runtime_error("Env var not found");
            it = cache_entries.insert({key, ptr}).first;
        }
        return it->second;
    }

    void clear() {
        cache_entries.clear();
    }
private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> cache_entries;
};

int main() {
    EnvCache cache;
    std::cout << cache.get_env("PATH") << std::endl;
}
```

You could invalidate cache entries in case you modify environment variables. You could also map directly to `const char*`, but that's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

A process inherits the environment from the process creating the new process. This is held in memory.

Indeed, In C and C++ you can define `main` to have an extra parameter that contains the environment - see http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments

Additionally you can use `extern char **environ;` to access the array containing the environment. (this is null terminated)

Therefore you do not need a cache. The environment variables are held in memory as an array.

Comment: C++ does not offer main functions which contain the environment. Thats a gcc extensions.

Comment: And I think while C does define the environment variable for main, nobody ever agreed on a standard for it, which means in practice it's completely useless and should be replaced with `getenv()`.

Comment: @smerlin, it's not just a gcc (or GNU) extension, it's a unix convention. The POSIX standard defines the global array as a portable way to access the environment, see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/environ.html - so if using C++ on a POSIX system it will work, nothing to do with GCC.

Comment: @JonathanWakely: i spoke about the main function taking a third parameter, not the global variable. His own link also mentions its not part of the POSIX standard. (`POSIX.1 does not allow this three-argument form, so to be portable it is best to write main to take two arguments, and use the value of environ.`)

Comment: @smerlin, yes, but that's still a unix convention, not gcc-specific. The glibc documentation linked to by Ed Heal even says so.