# How expensive it is to read an environment variable?

Tags: linux, performance, environment-variables

It's pretty common to read an environment variable and store it in a regular variable to reuse it along the way. Something like

```golang
myVal := os.GetEnv("FOO")
if myVal == "bar" {
  ...
}
```

But that got me wondering. Apart from readability, does that give any kind of performance boost to use a declared variable rather than using a `getEnv` method every time ?

To put it differently, is it more expensive to access anvironment variable than a declared variable, or is it exactly the same ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7460584/1518100

Comment: The chances that that is an actual performance bottleneck in your system are practically zero. Don't think performance comes from learning billions of rules and blindly applying them. If you have performance issues, *profile* your code and concentrate on the problem areas

Comment: Performances often come from understanding what you are doing, and having a good comprehension of the systems you are running; I'm not trying to solve any performance issue here, just being curious about something I don't know about :)

Comment: As long as you do not do it in a loop, it does not matter. And it is unlikely that anybody will do it in a loop.

Comment: If you assume environment variables are in shared memory (to avoid system calls) and are updated by lockless algorithms (e.g. atomically replace a pointer to the string rather than modifying the old string); and that to improve the speed of lookups the code uses hash tables; then we can say that for the fastest (least secure) possible implementation environment variable are still hideously expensive (compared to accessing a normal  variable). In general, as soon as someone says "Lets use plain text" (e.g. text names instead of an enumeration) you can expect several hundred times slower.